# Escapar comillas simples y dobles HTML JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente código jquery:

```
let nombre = `hola "asd" y 'zxc'`;
$("#n_selectprod").append('<div id="n_divselect'+cod+'" class="w-100 text-center text-success border-bottom py-1" onClick="sonidoClick();n_seleccion_select(this,\''+cod+'\',\''+barra+'\',\''+categoria+'\',\''+ncategoria+'\',\''+nombre+'\');">'+nombre+'</div>');
```

El problema surge con el nombre, si el nombre lleva comillas dobles entonces la función `n_seleccion_select` falla, intenté reemplazarlo con `&quot;`, ponerle `\`, nada funciona, una ayuda porfavor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné agregando un atributo llamado `nombre`, a la función `n_seleccion_select` le quité el parámetro donde iba el nombre, y ya que necesito usar el nombre dentro de la función, entonces dentro de `n_seleccion_select` coloqué `var nombre=$(elem).attr('nombre');`(elem es el parámetro this):

```
let nombre = `hola "asd" y 'zxc'`;
nombre=nombre.replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
nombre=nombre.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
$("#n_selectprod").append(`<div id="n_divselect`+cod+`" nombre="`+nombre+`" class="w-100 text-center text-success border-bottom py-1" onClick="sonidoClick();n_seleccion_select(this,'`+cod+`','`+barra+`','`+categoria+`','`+ncategoria+`');">`+nombre+`</div>`);
```